# What's the difference between "is null " AND "<=> NULL"

Tags: mysql, sql, null, isnull

What's the difference between `is null` and `<=> NULL`  ?

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM param WHERE num is null;
+-----+------+
| id  | num  |
+-----+------+
|   8 | NULL |
| 225 | NULL |
+-----+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM param WHERE num<>NULL;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM param WHERE num<=>NULL;
+-----+------+
| id  | num  |
+-----+------+
|   8 | NULL |
| 225 | NULL |
+-----+------+
```

difference in standards versions? I do not see the practical use of parameter `<=>` if it has `is null`

Comment: Have you read the documentation [Working with NULL Values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/working-with-null.html)?

Comment: YES!!!! I read this..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**NEVER** check for nulls using  `foo = null` or `foo <> null` or `foo != null`

```
mysql> SELECT 1 <> NULL;
        -> NULL
```

**Not even NULL is equal to NULL!**

```
mysql> SELECT NULL = NULL;
        -> NULL
```

Instead use one of the following operators

---

The `<=>` is the [Null-Safe Operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to)

> **NULL**-safe equal. This operator performs an equality comparison like the **=** operator, but returns `1` rather than **NULL** if both operands are **NULL**, and `0` rather than **NULL** if one operand is **NULL**.

```
mysql> SELECT 1 <=> 1, NULL <=> NULL, 1 <=> NULL;
        -> 1, 1, 0
mysql> SELECT 1 = 1, NULL = NULL, 1 = NULL;
        -> 1, NULL, NULL
```

---

On the other hand, [IS NULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is-null) is a little more straight forward

> Tests whether a value is **NULL**.

```
mysql> SELECT 1 IS NULL, 0 IS NULL, NULL IS NULL;
        -> 0, 0, 1
```

**Important:** Read the [IS NULL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is-null) to see how the `sql_auto_is_null` setting affects this operator.

**See also:** [IS NOT NULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is-not-null) to test for values *not* equal to NULL.

---

You might be interested in [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) too.

Answer (score 4):

## Theoretical difference

**`<=>` Operator**

[`<=>`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) is a safe null-comparison operator. That means you may use it and do not worry if you'll compare with `NULL` - it will behave properly. To illustrate, here is a simple query:

```
mysql> SELECT v, v<=>NULL, v<=>1, v<=>0 FROM test;
+------+----------+-------+-------+
| v    | v<=>NULL | v<=>1 | v<=>0 |
+------+----------+-------+-------+
|    1 |        0 |     1 |     0 |
| NULL |        1 |     0 |     0 |
+------+----------+-------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So what `<=>` does - is normal comparison, with paying attention is one or two compared operands are `NULL`.

**`IS NULL`**

On the other hand, [`IS NULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is-null) is very similar. It will check if checked argument is `NULL` or not. But - no, it's not exactly same as using `<=>` - at least, because `IS NULL` will return boolean value:

```
mysql> SELECT v, v IS NULL FROM test;
+------+-----------+
| v    | v IS NULL |
+------+-----------+
|    1 |         0 |
| NULL |         1 |
+------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**How they are equivalent**

But - **yes**, we can replace `<=>` with `IS NULL`, using [`IF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if). That will be done with:

```
mysql> SELECT v, IF(v IS NULL, 1, 0) AS `v<=>NULL`, IF(v IS NULL, 0, v=1) AS `v<=>1`, IF(v IS NULL, 0, v=0) AS `v<=>0` FROM test;
+------+----------+-------+-------+
| v    | v<=>NULL | v<=>1 | v<=>0 |
+------+----------+-------+-------+
|    1 |        0 |     1 |     0 |
| NULL |        1 |     0 |     0 |
+------+----------+-------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Thus, `<=>` is equivalent for combination of `IF`, `IS NULL` and plain comparison.

## Practical difference

I already said, that `<=>` can be replaced with `IS NULL` and `IF` - but `<=>`, actually, have one great benefit. It may be used safely in [**prepared statements**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html). Imagine that we want to check some condition with incoming value. Using `<=>` we can do this, using prepared statement:

```
mysql> PREPARE stmt FROM 'SELECT * FROM test WHERE v<=>?';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Statement prepared
```

And now we can just do not care if we'll pass `NULL` or not - it will work properly:

```
mysql> SET @x:=1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> EXECUTE stmt USING @x;
+------+
| v    |
+------+
|    1 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Or with `NULL`:

```
mysql> SET @x:=NULL;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> EXECUTE stmt USING @x;
+------+
| v    |
+------+
| NULL |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

That, of course, will be same for all drivers, which are relying on prepared statements (such as [PDO for PHP](https://www.php.net/pdo_mysql), for example).

Well. we *can* replace that with `IS NULL` - but `<=>` is a great thing to use in this case, so we can have our prepared statement short and clean.

Comment: this *is* a great benefit!

Comment: @Strawberry well, may be I'm wrong that it's the _only_ benefit - but, yes, it's definitely the thing, which make `<=>` very useful

Answer (score 2):

In practice, they're logically identical, so the following will both produce the same result...

```
SELECT NULL <=> NULL, 1 <=> NULL;
SELECT NULL IS NULL, 1 IS NULL;
```

But in the following situation, one will throw an error while the other will not...

```
SELECT 1 <=> 1;
SELECT 1 IS 1;
```

So, 'IS NULL' can only be used to test for 'nullness'. 'IS' cannot be employed except in conjunction with 'NULL'. "<=>" can be used in a broader range of contexts making it (in my view) extremely useful.

Answer (score 0):

What's logic  ?

```
mysql> SELECT NULL AND false;
+----------------+
| NULL AND false |
+----------------+
|              0 |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT NULL AND TRUE;
+---------------+
| NULL AND TRUE |
+---------------+
|          NULL |
+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```